# Elasticsearch query using $ .getJSON

Tags: elasticsearch, getjson

I am querying the following elasticsearch index, named job6, using the $ .getJSON statement due to implementation requirements.

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 5,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [{
            "_index": "job6",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2e2ed07786c01e9fd845b62fb86a693a",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "meta": {},
                "file": {
                    "extension": "txt",
                    "content_type": "text/plain",
                    "created": "2020-04-03T11:57:45.673+0000",
                    "last_modified": "2020-02-27T16:15:27.795+0000",
                    "last_accessed": "2020-04-03T11:57:45.673+0000",
                    "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:51.668+0000",
                    "filesize": 0,
                    "filename": "fichero0_borrador.txt",
                    "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\99.Borrador\\fichero0_borrador.txt"
                },
                "path": {
                    "root": "4cface21f575d5e5985e4e3889c278a3",
                    "virtual": "PM/carpeta0/99.Borrador/fichero0_borrador.txt",
                    "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\99.Borrador\\fichero0_borrador.txt"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "job6",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "6f475ff7ac21fc59f4edc34761d09",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "cadena0 A\n",
                "meta": {},
                "file": {
                    "extension": "txt",
                    "content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    "created": "2020-04-14T09:30:20.218+0000",
                    "last_modified": "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
                    "last_accessed": "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
                    "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:52.223+0000",
                    "filesize": 9,
                    "filename": "fichero0_A.txt",
                    "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\fichero0_A.txt"
                },
                "path": {
                    "root": "c073f96a8d16ebb2e604bebd4fe8b40",
                    "virtual": "PM/carpeta0/fichero0_A.txt",
                    "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\fichero0_A.txt"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "job6",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "7dfb102f2e64e99740a89b1cff7d92a3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "cadena1\n",
                "meta": {},
                "file": {
                    "extension": "txt",
                    "content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    "created": "2020-04-03T11:56:21.165+0000",
                    "last_modified": "2020-04-03T12:23:23.872+0000",
                    "last_accessed": "2020-04-03T12:23:23.872+0000",
                    "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:52.254+0000",
                    "filesize": 7,
                    "filename": "fichero1.txt",
                    "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta1\\fichero1.txt"
                },
                "path": {
                    "root": "7ff4e7b0e0c3172dbd29a23861ab2125",
                    "virtual": "PM/carpeta1/fichero1.txt",
                    "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta1\\fichero1.txt"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "job6",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "74f0e8c1cccf2f32b4d43673cfdca0",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "cadena2\n",
                "meta": {},
                "file": {
                    "extension": "txt",
                    "content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    "created": "2020-04-03T11:56:30.524+0000",
                    "last_modified": "2020-04-03T12:23:35.029+0000",
                    "last_accessed": "2020-04-03T12:23:35.029+0000",
                    "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:52.270+0000",
                    "filesize": 7,
                    "filename": "fichero2.txt",
                    "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta2\\fichero2.txt"
                },
                "path": {
                    "root": "fd0c8ae8a885725cfcaee774c72be43",
                    "virtual": "PM/carpeta2/fichero2.txt",
                    "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta2\\fichero2.txt"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "job6",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "8d6c56c0448bc4bfa17787923baa9c",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "cadenaX\n",
                "meta": {},
                "file": {
                    "extension": "txt",
                    "content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    "created": "2020-04-14T15:12:56.632+0000",
                    "last_modified": "2020-04-14T15:34:53.139+0000",
                    "last_accessed": "2020-04-14T15:34:53.139+0000",
                    "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T15:35:14.685+0000",
                    "filesize": 7,
                    "filename": "fichero_X.txt",
                    "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpetaX\\fichero_X.txt"
                },
                "path": {
                    "root": "f43118a935c6c7ef81ea65307759fc",
                    "virtual": "PM/carpetaX/fichero_X.txt",
                    "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpetaX\\fichero_X.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

using the following code. *** Using $.getJSON is a must ***

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

        var url = 'http://localhost:9200/job6/_search'

        //QUERY A                   
        var datos = 
        {   
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
                     },
            "from" : "0", "size" : "2"
        }
        ;


        //QUERY B                       
        /*
        var datos = 
        {"query": {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "fichero1.txt",
                    "default_field" : "file.filename"
                    }
                  }
        };
        */


        //QUERY C   
        /*
       var datos =                              
                    {       
                          "query": {
                                    "query_string": {                                   
                                        "query" : "fichero1.txt"            
                                                           }
                                       }
       }
       ;
       */          


        //QUERY D   
        /*
        var datos = 
        {
              "query": {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "all_fields" : true ,
                        "query" : "fichero1.txt"            
                                           }
                       }
        }
        ;                       
        */



        //QUERY E       
        /*
        var datos = 
        {
          "query": 
                {     "query_string": 
                    {     "query": "fichero1.txt",  "fields": ["file.filename"]      
                    }    
                }       
        }
        ;
        */


        //QUERY F   
        /*
        var datos = 
        {
             "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "file.filename" : "fichero1.txt"
                        }
                    }
        }
        ;
        */

        var input_jsonString = JSON.stringify(datos);
        console.log("input_jsonString=" + input_jsonString);


        $.getJSON(url, datos, function (jsonFromFile) {     

        var output_jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonFromFile);
        console.log("output_jsonString=" + output_jsonString);      

        }
    )

});      

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm only getting response from the following query A

```
var datos = {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "from": "0",
    "size": "2"
};
```

With answer

```
output_jsonString = {
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 5,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "job6",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2e2ed07786c01e9fd845b62fb86a693a",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "meta": {},
                    "file": {
                        "extension": "txt",
                        "content_type": "text/plain",
                        "created": "2020-04-03T11:57:45.673+0000",
                        "last_modified": "2020-02-27T16:15:27.795+0000",
                        "last_accessed": "2020-04-03T11:57:45.673+0000",
                        "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:51.668+0000",
                        "filesize": 0,
                        "filename": "fichero0_borrador.txt",
                        "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\99.Borrador\\fichero0_borrador.txt"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "root": "4cface21f575d5e5985e4e3889c278a3",
                        "virtual": "PM/carpeta0/99.Borrador/fichero0_borrador.txt",
                        "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\99.Borrador\\fichero0_borrador.txt"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "job6",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6f475ff7ac21fc59f4edc34761d09",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "content": "cadena0 A\n",
                    "meta": {},
                    "file": {
                        "extension": "txt",
                        "content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                        "created": "2020-04-14T09:30:20.218+0000",
                        "last_modified": "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
                        "last_accessed": "2020-04-14T09:46:02.930+0000",
                        "indexing_date": "2020-04-14T13:56:52.223+0000",
                        "filesize": 9,
                        "filename": "fichero0_A.txt",
                        "url": "file://C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\fichero0_A.txt"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "root": "c073f96a8d16ebb2e604bebd4fe8b40",
                        "virtual": "PM/carpeta0/fichero0_A.txt",
                        "real": "C:\\TMPM\\carpeta0\\fichero0_A.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

To check the value of the input query and the output obtained. I created variables 'input_jsonString' and 'output_jsonString' that I'm consulting using the command 'console.log'.

The problem I have is I am getting errors, all with the same characteristics, in the following types of queries. Named QUERY B, C, .. F in code (to check remove comments code). For example, for next query called C

`input_jsonString = {"query":{"query_string":{"query":"fichero1.txt"}}}`

I'm getting the following error:

```
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/job6/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query[query_string][query]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/job6/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query[query_string][query]]"},"status":400}
```

Although previously I had verified, through Kibana, that all the queries were coded correctly and from which I am getting the correct answer, all of them. Like in image of query C:

[image: Query C in Kibana]

Please, what mistake am i making?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're using `GET` instead of `POST`, thereby the exceptions. If you **have** to use `GET`, make your queries [URI-Search-friendly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html).

---

If you need to be using jQuery and cannot take advantage of the official [ES JS Client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js), you'll need to use a `POST` request, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "http://localhost:9200/_all/_search";

        //QUERY A
        var a = {
          query: {
            match_all: {}
          },
          from: "0",
          size: "2"
        };
        //QUERY B

        var b = {
          query: {
            query_string: {
              query: "fichero1.txt",
              default_field: "file.filename"
            }
          }
        };

        //QUERY C

        var c = {
          query: {
            query_string: {
              query: "fichero1.txt"
            }
          }
        };
        //QUERY D

        var d = {
          query: {
            simple_query_string: {
              all_fields: true,
              query: "fichero1.txt"
            }
          }
        };

        //QUERY E

        var e = {
          query: {
            query_string: { query: "fichero1.txt", fields: ["file.filename"] }
          }
        };

        //QUERY F

        var f = {
          query: {
            match: {
              "file.filename": "fichero1.txt"
            }
          }
        };

        var problematic = {
          query: { query_string: { query: "fichero1.txt" } }
        };

        [a, b, c, d, e, f, problematic].map(function (query) {
          $.ajax({
            url,
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(query),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              console.log({ query, response });
            },
            error: function (err) {
              console.error({ query, err });
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

FYI `http://localhost:9200` will almost certainly not be accessible in production.

Comment: In addition, calling Elasticsearch directly from the client side poses a real security risk, as it will either be unsecured, or credentials will be easily obtainable.

Comment: I used your map function successfully. How should i make the call? Calling from my code to kibana? Thank you

Comment: No. You should be calling a secured (backend) endpoint whereby the connection to ES only gets established within that backend. FYI "Kibana" is the UI interface to ES -- you cannot send requests "to Kibana".

Comment: Put `"size": 100` on the top level of your query... The default is 20 so I'm wondering you're getting 10... Are you sure the filters don't limit them to 10?